# GAS syncing backend scripting with page load

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, settimeout

In my html code I call a script to edit a google form, then loads that form. My problem, the web page loads before the script is done updating.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <script>
  google.script.run.changeForm();     
  window.top.location.href='https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/ABCDpQLSdV2e61UFkG-_LcVBRpWe9F1MizNJ-P5JUCUGRlWiFSoImPkA/viewform';
  </script>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

My temporary fix is to setTimeout(), but this feels a like a dirty little trick.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <script>
  google.script.run.changeForm();  
  setTimeout(function(){  
  window.top.location.href='https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/ABCDpQLSdV2e61UFkG-_LcVBRpWe9F1MizNJ-P5JUCUGRlWiFSoImPkA/viewform';
  }, 2000);
  </script>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).changeForm();
function success(){
window.top.location.href='https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/ABCDpQLSdV2e61UFkG-_LcVBRpWe9F1MizNJ-P5JUCUGRlWiFSoImPkA/viewform';
}
```

`withSuccessHandler(success)` run the function in parameter after your function `changeForm()`has finished his execution